# Pyspark Group a Dataframe by Multiple Keys in Parallel

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I need to group a dataframe by all possible column combinations and output the count.

For example:

***df:***

| col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- |
| val1 | val2 |

***combination_list:***

[**[col1]**, **[col2]**, **[col1, col2]**]

the number of combination = 2^n - 1, meaning I need to do 2^n -1 times groupby operation.

I have tried:

```
for c in combination_list:
  df_result = df.groupby(c).count()
  df_result.repartition(1).write.csv('file_path')
```

This is very slow as I have hundreds of combinations and I know for loop should be avoided in pyspark. **How can I conduct groupby for all the combinations in the list in parallel?**

Comment: @ARCrow Thanks for the suggestion! but how is window operations applicable in this case?

Comment: a window is applicable because if you wanted to group by multiple combinations, you'd have to take the dataframe, and do all your different group bys. If you do a window, you can do all the different group bys on the same dataframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The operation you are looking for is [`cube`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.cube.html).
Cube generates aggregations for all combination of columns passed as arguements.

```py
data = [("c1v1", "c2v1",),
        ("c1v2", "c2v2",),
        ("c1v1", "c2v2",), ]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ("col1", "col2"))

df.show()

"""
+----+----+
|col1|col2|
+----+----+
|c1v1|c2v1|
|c1v2|c2v2|
|c1v1|c2v2|
+----+----+
"""

df.cube(df.columns).count().show()

"""
+----+----+-----+
|col1|col2|count|
+----+----+-----+
|c1v2|c2v2|    1|
|c1v1|c2v1|    1|
|c1v1|c2v2|    1|
|null|null|    3|
|null|c2v2|    2|
|null|c2v1|    1|
|c1v2|null|    1|
|c1v1|null|    2|
+----+----+-----+
"""
```